# Servable not found for request: while loading an older version of the model

Tags: grpc, tensorflow-serving

I've a model, let's say **mymodel** and two different data sets: **setA**, **setB**.

After training(in my local machine) *setA* and *setB* separately, tensorflow serving created two different directories: **100**, **200** for *setA* and *setB* respectively.

**To host the model inside docker**

```
root@ccb58054cae5:/# ls /serving/model/
100 200
root@ccb58054cae5:/# bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/tensorflow_model_server --port=9000 --model_name=mymodel --model_base_path=/serving/model &> log &
```

Now when I do the inference for *setB*, I'm successfully able to get the response, as tensorflow serving by default loads *200* because it thinks this is the latest model.

Now I want to query for *setA*, so I need to mention in the code which version of the hosted model to hit and that would be *100*.

In terms of code: `request.model_spec.version.value = 100`

for completeness here is the other relevant client code:

```
host, port = FLAGS.server.split(':')
channel = implementations.insecure_channel(host, int(port))
stub = prediction_service_pb2.beta_create_PredictionService_stub(channel)
request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
request.model_spec.name = 'mymodel'
request.model_spec.signature_name = signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY
request.model_spec.version.value = 100
```

I got to know about `request.model_spec.version.value = 100` from [here](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!topic/discuss/06GQIMLU_vY). But I got unlucky, I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\grpc\beta\_client_adaptations.py", line 193, in _blocking_unary_unary
    credentials=_credentials(protocol_options))
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 492, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, deadline)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 440, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.NOT_FOUND, Servable not found for request: Specific(mymodel, 100))>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py", line 188, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "mymodel.py", line 63, in json_test
    response =  main.main(ser, query = que)
  File "D:\mymodel_temp\temp\main.py", line 23, in main
    return json_for_inference(model.inference(query), query, service_id)
  File "D:\mymodel_temp\temp\src\utils.py", line 30, in wrapper
    outputs = function(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\mymodel_temp\temp\src\model.py", line 324, in inference
    result = stub.Predict(request, 10.0) # 10 seconds
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\grpc\beta\_client_adaptations.py", line 309, in __call__
    self._request_serializer, self._response_deserializer)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\grpc\beta\_client_adaptations.py", line 195, in _blocking_unary_unary
    raise _abortion_error(rpc_error_call)
grpc.framework.interfaces.face.face.AbortionError: AbortionError(code=StatusCode.NOT_FOUND, details="Servable not found for request: Specific(mymodel, 100)")
```

Answer (score 5):

You are getting `Servable not found for request: Specific(mymodel, 100)` error, because there is no model loaded with this specific version number.

```
root@ccb58054cae5:/# bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/tensorflow_model_server --port=9000 --model_name=mymodel --model_base_path=/serving/model &> log &
```

When you run above command on docker for serving models, it will load model according to **Version Policy** mentioned [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/sources/storage_path/file_system_storage_path_source.proto#L12) in Git Code of Tensorflow Serving. By default only one version of model will be loaded and that version will be ***Latest one*** (Higher version number).

If you want to load multiple versions or multiple models, you need to add `--model_config_file` flag. Also remove `--model_name` and `--model_base_path` flags as we will be adding them in model config file.

So now your command will be like this :-

```
root@ccb58054cae5:/# bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/tensorflow_model_server --port=9000 --model_config_file=mymodel.conf &> log &
```

Format of model config file will be like this :-

```
model_config_list: {

    config: {
        name: "mymodel",
        base_path: "/serving/model",
        model_platform: "tensorflow"
        model_version_policy: {all{}}
    }
}
```

So you can set Version Policy other than `latest` (By Default) to `all` and `specific`. By selecting `all` , you can load all versions of model as servables and then you can easily access specific version using   `request.model_spec.version.value = 100` in client code. If you want to load more than one models, you can do that in same config file by appending model config for those models.